# In Wire Gauges Is ga shorthand for awg?

Tags: wire

Is GA shorthand for AWG (American Wire Gauge)?  Someone seemed to use the terms interchangeably in [this question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/876/37) and then never let me know if they were interchangeable terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GA is short for gauge.

The approved gauge for electrical conductors in the US is American Wire Gauge.

There are other methods to gauge wire.

Comment: So if they mentioned AWG elsewhere and then referred to GA they probably mean the AWG wire gauge?

Comment: Yes, 'ga' is an accepted abreviation for the word gauge. And when talking about electrical conductors most people mean AWG. When you get larger than 4/0 wire though it switches to Circular Mils.